# Connect jsp to Database - DAO

Tags: hibernate, web-applications, struts2

Good morning, i have this problem.I should connect a database with a  DAO ( where is a query ) and , i should view  in my JSP the bean assosciate at this DAO.I implement this code but doesnt work nothing.Initially i connect a bean with the jsp and the method provajsp,then i try to connect  the bean the jsp and the DAO class,but really dont know what i do , i need a little help if its possible.thanks a lot

CLASS ORGANIC ACTION

```
private List<StudentNational> listStudent=new ArrayList<StudentNational>()  ;


     private List<Bean> empList = new ArrayList<Bean>();




public List<StudentNational> getListStudent() {
        return listStudent;

    }

public void setListStudent(List<StudentNational> listStudent)   { 
        this.listStudent=listStudent;
    }
```

CLASS ORGANIC SERVICE IMPL

```
        @Override
    public List <Bean> provajsp() throws Exception {

        List <Bean> result = StudentNationalDAO.provajsp();
        Iterator<Bean> it = result.iterator();
        Bean obj = null;


            String name= obj.getName();
            String surname= obj.getSurname();
            return StudentNational.provajsp();
```

CLASS BEAN

```
private String name;
    private String surname;
    with getter and setter
```

STUDENT NATIONAL contains table with fields 
table

CLASSE StudentNationalDAO IMPL

```
List<StudentNational> result = null;
            String sqlNative = " Select * FROM StudentNational";            

            Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlNative);



            result = query.getResultList();
            return result;
```

and the JSP which contains the iterator for view the page .

Comment: This ` Bean obj = null; String name= obj.getName();` must give you NullPointerException.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is.